# Adding a background image to a JFrame using Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jframe

Hello i have been following multiple guides on how to add a background image to a JFrame. However when run my program, the background turns out with only a bit of the background image showing in the bottom left and bottom sides.

Here is my current code:

```
private int width = 1280;
private int height = 720;

private String title = "Creation - " + Component.versionID + " Launcher";

private JPanel window = new JPanel();
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JLabel name, version;


private JButton play, options, changelog, quit;
private Rectangle rPlay, rOptions, rChangelog, rQuit, rName, rVersion;
private int buttonWidth = 200;
private int buttonHeight = 80;

public Menu (Component component) {
    frame.setTitle(title);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(component);
    frame.getContentPane().add(window);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("res/icon.png").getImage());

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/background.png"));
    frame.add(background);
    background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    window.setLayout(null);
    drawButtons();
    frame.repaint();
    frame.pack();
}

private void drawButtons() {

    name = new JLabel("Creation");
    rName = new Rectangle((width/2) - (buttonWidth/2) + 60, 20, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    name.setBounds(rName);
    window.add(name);

    play = new JButton("Play");
    rPlay = new Rectangle((width/2) - (buttonWidth/2), 250, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    play.setBounds(rPlay);
    window.add(play);

    options = new JButton("Options");
    rOptions = new Rectangle((width/2) - (buttonWidth/2), 350, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    options.setBounds(rOptions);
    window.add(options);

    changelog = new JButton("View change-log");
    rChangelog = new Rectangle((width/2) - (buttonWidth/2), 450, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    changelog.setBounds(rChangelog);
    window.add(changelog);

    quit = new JButton("Quit");
    rQuit = new Rectangle((width/2) - (buttonWidth/2), 550, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    quit.setBounds(rQuit);
    window.add(quit);

    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component component = new Component();
            frame.dispose();
            component.start();
        }
    });
    options.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    changelog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

(As you can see) my JFrame size is 1280x720. This is the same size as the background image, so I don't see any issues. If anyone could help me edit my code or give me pointers, I am simply looking for the background image to display behind the buttons.

Comment: *"JFrame size is 1280x720. This is the same size as the background image"*...no, it won't be.  A frame has decorations, this means the space available to the application is going to be the `frame.size - frame border insets`. Instead of setting the frame size directly, use a custom component that returns the `preferredSize` of the content area and use this as the frames content pane...

Answer (score 3):

1. If your GUI will be the size of the image, then add the BufferedImage to the JLabel, and add the **JLabel** the to the JFrame's contentPane, not some JPanel that doesn't display the image.
2. Don't use null layout and `setBounds(...)` but instead use decent layout managers. While null layout *seems* easier to newbies, that's usually just because you may be unfamiliar with how to use layout managers, and trust me, it is *much* easier to create and maintain GUI's that use well-behaved layout managers.
3. Give that JPanel/contentPane a decent layout since you'll be adding components to it.

Comment: Hello, I am very new to coding in Java, could you please provide me some example code of what this would look like? Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: We are not here to write code for you. Try to write the code yourself. If there is something you don't understand then ask a follow up question about the part you don't understand. You can start by reading the Swing tutorial which has the basics of using Swing.

Answer (score 0):

```
String filename = "demo//6.jpg";

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));

//Create Image Label
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
label.setBounds(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
lpane.setLayout(null);
lpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
lpane.add(label, new Integer(JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER-1));
ImageIcon ic=new ImageIcon("demo//12.jpg");
but.setIcon(ic);
```

Answer (score 0):

class MyFrame
{

```
public static void main(String arr[])
{
   JPanel panel=new JPanel()
   {
       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
       {
           try
           {
               BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C://Users//MulayamYadav//Desktop//1.jpg"));
               Image image1=image.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
               g.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
              System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
   };
   JFrame frame=new JFrame();
   panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   panel.add(new JButton("Button1"));
   panel.add(new JButton("Button2"));
   add(panel);
   frame.setVisible(true);
```

}